# Azure - Continously Running WebJob: support for Node.JS and Documentation

Tags: node.js, azure-web-app-service

What language options do we have for deploying full cloud-native continuously running apps in App Service?

Azure documentation portal promotes WebJobs SDK with its easily manageable services binding, etc. - but then all examples are only provided for C#.

Is there an option to use WebJobs SDK with other supported executable runtimes - like Node.JS (we'd actually preferred Python, but it's no longer supported on Windows - and WebJobs SDK is not supported on Linux either, so I guess Python is not an option then)?

Where can we find full documentation for creating WebJobs with Node.js?

Let's say our continuously running job will be monitoring (polling) Blob Storage for new file arrival; Work with Azure Batch APIs to initiate file processing and track processing status (including polling); store state in SQL Database, etc.

If we're to choose between C# and Node.js, what exactly we're missing out by choosing node.js - or why C# would be preferable (except it's the only one which is properly documented...)?

Thanks!

Comment: Is there any reason you are preferring WebJobs over [Azure Functions](https://azure.microsoft.com/services/functions/) which is the newer sever-less compute, more advanced than WebJobs, has support for multiple languages both in Windows and Linux and have extensive [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/azure-functions/) for all supported languages. If there is no other reason of not going for Functions in your case, I will propose it as answer.

Comment: Well, I thought Functions are primarily for short-lived "Function"-like (microservice) integration pattern. In this case, we were looking to deploy a continously-running daemon.

Comment: Ultimately, your purpose is to respond to a trigger (for example, blob upload, http, timer etc.) which will execute Function. Not sure what more you want to achieve using continuous running daemon.